# Retrieve a hashmap from firebase to populate FirebaseRecycler, null HashMap

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview, firebaseui

I am trying to retrieve a HashMap from Firebase to populate my Firebase `RecyclerView` below is my model class that I am trying to retrieve:

```
public class Employee{
private HashMap<String, Person> PeopleMap; 
// =  new HashMap<String, Person>();

public Employee () {
}

public Employee(HashMap<String, Person> people) {
    this.PeopleMap= people;
}

public HashMap<String, Person> getMap() {
    return PeopleMap;
}
public void setMap(HashMap<String, Person> people) {
    this.PeopleMap= people;
}
}
```

Person class

```
public class Person {
private String ImageUrl;
private  String Name;
private String  Pay;
public Person() {
}

public Person(String name, String imageUrl, String pay, 
 ) {
    ImageUrl = imageUrl;
    Name = name;
    Pay = pay;

}

public String getImageUrl() {
    return ImageUrl;
}

public void setImageUrl(String imageUrl) {
    ImageUrl = imageUrl;
}

public String getName() {
    return Name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    Name = name;
}

public String getPay() {
    return Pay;
}

public void setPrice(String pay) {
    Pay= pay;
}
}
```

Now the problem is that when i retrieve my Employe model class in firebase recycler it is not null but if i retrieve my Hashmap from there the size of map is zero while there are items on the map below is what i am doing

Firebase REycler

```
        @Override
        protected void onBindViewHolder( ConvoViewHolder holder,  int 
        position,  Employee model) {
            if (model.equals(null)){
                Toast.makeText(OrderConversation.this, "object is null", 
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            else
            {
                HashMap<String, OrderItem> cartitems =  model.getCart();
                int i = cartitems.size();
             if (i==0)
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(OrderConversation.this, "null 
                        map", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                    else {
                        Toast.makeText(OrderConversation.this, "size of 
                        map in bind"+ Integer.toString(i),
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
            }
        }
    };
    mEmpList.setAdapter(adapter);
    adapter.startListening();
```

My Database structure is like below with employee as a parent node and

[image]

Sorry I had to type it i hope it is clear to everyone about what kind of str i have. i want to retrieve from department node so that i can get two object (DHead1 & Dhead2 ),  which have different no of elements in them as Dhead has 3 objects of person class and Dhead2 has 2. so one way i can go is either i load them first into a list and them use them or the other way that i am using now i.e. retrieve them as an object which contains the map of person class object.

i tried this below and i am getting values fine but inside onbindview its not working

```
mDatabase.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
             @Override
             public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                 for(DataSnapshot ds: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                     GenericTypeIndicator<Map<String, Person>> to = new 
                     GenericTypeIndicator<Map<String, Person>>() {};
                     Map<String, Person> map = ds.getValue(to);
                     for(Person ml:convoModels.values()) {
                         String name = ml.getName();
                         Toast.makeText(context, "name is "+ name, 
                         Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                     }
                   }
              }
             @Override
             public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
             }
         });
```

Comment: **[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49383687/how-can-i-retrieve-data-from-firebase-to-my-adapter/49384849)** is a recommended way in which you can retrieve data from a Firebase Realtime database and display it in a `RecyclerView` using `FirebaseRecyclerAdapter`.

Comment: @AlexMamo I want to retrieve a Employee model object from firebase. I am following the same steps but my model object contains a hashmap which i want to use that hasmap but my model class is returning null here why is that

Comment: i have stored my Person class object in firebase and i want to retrieve a list of those objects under a node from firebase. Is there any other way to get an object(with list of objects inside) from firebase

Comment: In this case, please add your database structure.

Comment: i have updated it please see if you can help and sorry i don't have the system with me right now otherwise i would have uploaded the exact structure but i have tried to simplify it

Comment: The strcuture is ok but I need to see how your fields are stored in your real database (a simple screenshot will be fine).

Comment: @AlexMamo i have uploaded a pic is this what you want to see ?

Answer (score 2):

You are not getting anything because the fields in your model class are different than the fileds in your database. See, in your database you have `imageUrl` and in your model class you have `ImageUrl`. Keep in mind that when you are using a getter named `getImageUrl()`, Firebase will search for a field named `imageUrl` and not `ImageUrl`. The key for solving your problem is to change the name of your fields so it can start with a lower case like this:

```
private String imageUrl;
private  String name;
private String  pay;
```

**Edit:** See also the correct way of using the `Employee` class.

```
public class Employee {
    private HashMap<String, Person> peopleMap;

    public Employee() {}

    public Employee(HashMap<String, Person> peopleMap) {
        this.peopleMap = peopleMap;
    }

    public HashMap<String, Person> getPeopleMap() {
        return peopleMap;
    }
}
```

Comment: the app crashes as soon as the values are called, it shows error calling size() on a null object

Comment: This was also the bahaviour before?

Comment: yes, i was sure that something is wrong with my model class, but now  i think  when i call the values from the database the values are not coming as hashmap of object of my model class

Comment: The problem in your code is that `model.getCart()` return `null` and this also because you model class is wrong. Your model should look like in my updated answer. Does it work now?

Comment: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.util.HashMap.equals(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference still same error

Comment: what alex says about the variable names is super important since if they are different from the database and your model you cant reach any value to work with

Comment: @GastónSaillén Thanks Gastón for your comment. You're right.

Comment: i have been throught this when it happened to me for about an entire day to figure it out back in the days haha

Comment: @Jimmy Is the same `NullPointerException` error but it occures now in a different place. With other words, the fist (initial) issue is solved. The second error occurs on this line of code `model.equals(null)`? Or in another place? Place indicate the exact place.

Comment: no actually i changed the same code  now it is still the same error on the same place

Comment: @GastónSaillén thank you for the info but now i have checked every variable but still cant get my hashmap from database

Comment: when i try to use the retrieved hashmap it displays -  invoke virtual method 'boolean java.util.HashMap.equals(java.lang.Object)' on a null object  reference

Comment: @Jimmy Please indicate us the exact line where you are getting this error.

Comment: @AlexMamo it is the same line where I am getting the error, i just changed a method thats all the hasmap is still null nothing has changed so far, the error is still there on the same line.i was trying to check something to i changed a method that all.

Comment: can you guys provide some code example / links  where similar way of retrieving hashmap is used

Comment: @Jimmy When you are trying to get an object of your `Employee` class to the database, which has a single property, the `peopleMap` map, point the reference on the a particula node which must be of type `Employee` and then use the getter to actually get the map back, right?

Comment: Is there everything alright, can I help you with other informations?

Comment: @AlexMamo i am still stuck and i tried using listener on my database the model class is fine and it is showing values check above i have added some code i used GenericTypeIndicator to retrieve values and they are coming fine.

Comment: There is no need to use a `GenericTypeIndicator` just follow my last comment.

Comment: @AlexMamo i used GenericTypeIndicator just to check whether my model class is correct or not and turns out its working fine. and about your last comment i am calling the same node i dont know why it is still returning null.

Comment: @AlexMamo i tried using a custom adapter to populate my recycler view, but still am getting some issues withit can you also look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51706961/hashmap-is-not-attached-to-adapter it is related to the same problem. i am loading these values in a map first and then using the same map to populate the view but somehow my map is gettng attached to the adapter.

Comment: @AlexMamo i use same node point  in both the cases and  the result is coming on only when i use GenericTypeIndicator

Comment: @AlexMamo When i use GenericTypeIndicator it is giving me value fine but not inside firebase adapter.

Comment: what is mean is its working inside valueeventlistener(see the code above) on the same database node using the GenericTypeIndicator.

Comment: I understand and do you think that my answer helped you?

Comment: yes a little bit i will give you one up, i trying some other way here also but i dont know why my Map is getting attached to my Adapter can you please help me with this i am stuck here i cant use firebase adapter and now i cant use custom adapter also please have a look at it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51706961/hashmap-is-not-attached-to-adapter it will be a great help thanks

Comment: This is basically another question. In order to follow the rules of this comunity, please post another fresh question, so me and other users can help you.

Comment: Yes i have posted it as another question that's why I provided the link above it is the question that i posted yesterday, i tried the other way for using my values but somehow my Map is not getting attached to my adapter can you please have a look at it